# Unable to install any modules (nodes) in Node-RED on hassio

Tags: module, raspberry-pi, node-red

I am unable to install any modules (nodes) in Node-RED on hassio running on a Raspberry Pi. It worked previously, but does not now. I have not changed any configuration although it is possible that node-red auto updated. When I attempt to install, I get this error:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.6.0
npm info using node@v10.0.0
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red-contrib-telegrambot-home failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-30T01_39_51_895Z-debug.log
```

There is no proxy. I tried to edit `package.json` to add the modules to dependencies but that also did not work.

Comment: It can't connect to registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443, this is purely network issue. Try to ping there hosts.

Comment: Hmm. No problems with ping from the RPi.

`PING registry.npmjs.org (151.101.0.162): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.0.162: seq=0 ttl=51 time=29.951 ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DNS problem. Pi-Hole was also running on the RPi and causing the issue. Set DNS to Google using [this info](https://docs.resin.io/reference/resinOS/network/2.x/).